# Amazon s3 storage design for video site

Tags: amazon-s3

we have thousands of videos in our video site, we plan to use amazon-s3 for storage on cloud. videos are in following hierarchy.

root -> channels -> shows -> seasons -> episodes -> video clips.

each video clip will have different bit rate versions, thumbnails of different sizes, also a mobile version of video. (3gp)

I have few basic questions on s3.

1) how many buckets should be used and what should be a logical bucket? (one bucket/channel or only one bucket with channel as sub-folder)?

2) does the performance of s3 bucket reduce due to lot of concurrent read/write requests on single bucket?, does it help having multiple buckets and read/write gets distributed, also if lets say one bucket goes down, I can still server content from other bucket?

3) any documentation of how s3 is used for large multimedia site?

Comment: Is rest of your application deployed on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably stay away from separating between buckets (as I recall there's a max. number of buckets which you can create).

Instead I'd use a single bucket with path type names, e.g.

channelx/showx/seasonx/epx/clipx

Amazons web UI will even recognise these as directories so you can navigate them more easily.

> does the performance of s3 bucket reduce due to lot of concurrent read/write requests on
>   single bucket?,

Not that I know of, I would hope they'd automatically replicate to handle this.

One more tip, for a video site be very wary of S3's bandwidth charges. If you haven't looked they're probably much higher than you're expecting.